# Can I get instance specific sever URL of Salesforce by using Salesforce Session Id?

Tags: soap, salesforce

I am trying to access username (using SOAP calls) of Salesforce using Session Id only, I don't have access to instance specific server URL. (I know when you get session id, you also get server url, it's a long story and for my use-case I have only session id).

Any feedback will be much appreciated !

Thanks,
Nitesh

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you have is a sessionId, then i don't think you can find it out, you need either the sessionId + instanceUrl or sessionId + user id service Url.

Comment: Is there a way from which I can tell if the instanceUrl is for production salesforce or not (just by looking at it)?

Comment: you can infer it from the hostname, but that's not supported and possible that it'll break in the future, and won't work for customers using the my domains feature.

Comment: OK. Is there a query I can do and pass my session id and serverUrl, to check if its sandbox or production?

Comment: you should really start a new question.